# WooCommerce: Change priority of tabs by number of product ratings

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code that set reviews tab to show first before item description.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_reorder_tabs', 98 );
function woo_reorder_tabs( $tabs ) {
    $tabs['reviews']['priority'] = 5;           // Reviews first
    $tabs['description']['priority'] = 10;      // Description second
    return $tabs;
}
```

Its works fine, But i want to set it to do it only if the number of reviews high from 0.
Something like :

```
function woo_reorder_tabs( $tabs ) {
    if(is_review()){
        $tabs['reviews']['priority'] = 5;           // Reviews first
        $tabs['description']['priority'] = 10;      // Description second
        return $tabs;
    }
}
```

Is there any hook/ function / filter to get number of product reviews?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reviews in woocommerce is just comments in wordpress... so using [get_comments_number](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_comments_number) should work.

```
function woo_reorder_tabs( $tabs ) {
    if(get_comments_number() > 0){
        $tabs['reviews']['priority'] = 5;           // Reviews first
        $tabs['description']['priority'] = 10;      // Description second
    }
    return $tabs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code didn't work above. You need to add in both parts for it to work. **See below.**

```js
/*Reorder Reviews tab to be first*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_reorder_tabs', 98 );
function woo_reorder_tabs( $tabs ) {
    if(get_comments_number() > 0){
    $tabs['reviews']['priority'] = 5;           // Reviews first
    $tabs['description']['priority'] = 10;      // Description second
    }
        return $tabs;
}
```

Comment: The first answer was posted in 2015 which has been accepted also. You posted your answer in April, 2021. So it would be better if you mention that your answer is based on updated/new changes in the framework. It will not be wise to say that "Above code didn't work" after 5 years. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer